# Using Set - Removes duplicates automatically?

Tags: java, collections, set, duplicates

I have a class as below (Bean):

```
class KeysHolder {
   Long kitId;
   String packId;
   String boxId;

   // getters and setters
    .......
   // @Override equals and hashCode
}
```

I have a set that contains the above Objects

```
 Set<KeysHolder> keys;
```

Now if I keep adding the object to the set, does it automatically remove duplicates based on the values of the each elements? (I understand it uses Overridden equals and hashCode methods internally).

The final set should not contain any duplicates based on each field equality.

```
  obja.kitId = objb.kitId
  objb.packid = objb.packId
  obja.boxId = objb.boxId
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now if I keep adding the object to the set, does it automatically remove duplicates based on the values of the each elements.

The element if found duplicate by the `Set` implementation ,wouldn't be inserted at all.

From the Javadocs of [HashSet#add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29):

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that **(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))**. If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was intending to say after all. :-) Thanks anyways

Comment: So it does not add duplicate elements based on the each element equality?

Comment: Correct at least the doc says so , internally it `HashSet` uses `Hashmap#put()`.

Comment: KevinRave As @TheNewIdiot said, Hashset internally uses HashMap, just check post for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is *yes*, any set will perform the de-duplication by itself. But that's only guaranteed if you respect the contract; and the contract is a bit different for each `Set` implementation:

For a `HashSet`, as you noticed, you have to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`. But that's not enough: if you keep *mutable* instances in a `HashSet` and you modify the properties which affect the `hashCode()`/`equals()` result, you'll still end up in a weird situation.

With a `TreeSet`, on the other hand, you need to make sure that your `Comparable.compareTo()` or `Comparator.compare()` methods are consistent with `equals()`.

So read the documentation of `Set` and the one of the actual implementation that suits your needs and try to stick to the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any `Set` implementation would not allow duplicates.

But, it comes with a caveat. For a `Set` and other hash-based collections you need to make sure that the objects that you try to insert override their `equals()` as well as `hashCode()` method correctly.

By correct, I mean that `equals()` should return `true` for two meaningfully equivalent objects and that the `hashCode()` should try to return as disparate values as possible for the range of objects in your input set.

While an improper `equals()` implementation would most likely break your program; an inefficient `hashCode()` implementation would degrade your `Set`'s performance i.e. operations like `add()`, `contains()` etc. would be as slow as bad the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

HashSet internally uses HashMap, this map is maintained with key as the value that you want to add in the set and value is an instance of an Object class( **final private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();**). Now, when you add same object to this set, its the same operation that map does when you do map.put with the same on the same key, just updating the value.

However the value to be updated still remains the same which is **PRESENT**. And hence in a way you can say that set does not add **same** value. Though actually, map which is used internally to implement this set is updating itself with ****same*** key* and same value(PRESENT).

Answer (score 0):

I have written an example to illustrate how to remove duplicate employee entry in a set based one field in the class, here `name`:

```
public class Employee {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    public Employee(String i, String n, String a) {
        id = i; name = n; age = a;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) { 
            return true; 
        } 

        if (!(obj instanceof Employee)) { 
            return false; 
        }

        Employee e = (Employee) obj;

        return name.equals(e.name); 
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " " + name + " " + age;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("1", "abc", "10");
        Employee e2 = new Employee("2", "def", "20");
        Employee e3 = new Employee("3", "abc", "30");
        HashSet<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<>();
        empSet.add(e1);
        empSet.add(e2);
        empSet.add(e3);
        System.out.println(empSet.toString());
    }
}
```

All I needed to do is override methods `hashCode` and `equals` in Employee class.  It prints:

```
[1 abc 10, 2 def 20]
```